# Getter methods of a Class are Thread Safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a HashMap that look something like this-

```
 HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableList
```

which means it's value is a Class `TableConnectionInfo` which looks something like this-

```
public class TableConnectionInfo {

    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String password;
    public String driver;
    public String suffix;
    public String sql;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }

    public void setSql(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

}
```

In the main thread, I am populating the above map by reading it from the properties file like this and after that this map won't get modified.

```
    for (String arg : databaseNames) {

        TableConnectionInfo ci = new TableConnectionInfo();

        String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
        String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
        String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
        String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");
        String suffix = prop.getProperty(arg + ".suffix");
        String sql = prop.getProperty(arg + ".sql");

        ci.setUrl(url);
        ci.setDriver(driver);
        ci.setPassword(password);
        ci.setSql(sql);
        ci.setSuffix(suffix);
        ci.setUser(user);
        tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }
```

Now I am passing this `tableList` map to various threads like this and it won't be modified (by making set calls) by any thread. Each thread will be using get method to get the required method.

```
for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
    service.submit(new Task(tableList));
}
```

Below is my Task class that impelements Runnable Interface

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
    private CallableStatement[] callableStatement = null;
    private ArrayList<Method> methods[] = null;

    private final HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableLists;

    public Task(HashMap<String, TableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            int j = 0;
            dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];
            callableStatement = new CallableStatement[tableLists.size()];
            methods = new ArrayList[tableLists.size()];

            for (TableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {

                dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(),  ci.getDriver());
                callableStatement[j] = dbConnection[j].prepareCall(ci.getSql());

                methods[j] = getRequiredMethods(ci.getSuffix());
                j++;
            }

          }
             }
       }
```

**Question:-**

Now my question is- In my run method, I am calling get Methods of `TableConnectionInfo` class so it will be thread safe or not? As multiple threads will try to making get calls. So I am not sure whether I need to do anything extra here? Or the code looks fine?

Comment: You are using only getters in the run method, you are not modifying anything. Why are you then worried about thread safety?

Comment: A better design is to make the fields private and final. Use a constructor to initialize the object. If possible, remove the setters and provide getters. It is equivalent in terms of thread-safety (that is: safe) but the benefit is that it is much clearer to the reader.

Comment: Given your usage, you should be OK. The thing to avoid is calls of the form `tableslist.get(key).getXXX();tableslist.get(key).getYYY();` because the `get(key)` may not return the same object. Do note this line: "If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined." The safe way to do this is to create a new collection (eg. ArrayList) from `values` so that you are iterating over a copy,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference value (and primitive for that matter) assignment in Java is atomic. You don't have to worry about a reference value being in some sort of half-assigned state like you would in a lower level language.

That being said, yes, calling the getters in your class is thread-safe because they are just accessing `String` objects which are immutable BUT ... if some other thread has changed one via a setter you may not get the *current value* because of caching. You want to declare all your `String` variables in `TableConnectionInfo` as `volatile`.  This keeps a thread from caching an old value and thus the getter returning it to you.

If your `TableConnectionInfo` contained more complex objects (such as `List`s or `Map`s) that the getters were accessing while other threads could be changing ... then that's a different story. Concurrent modifications to mutable, complex data structures is different and would require synchronization.

Which ... points toward your `tableList`. If **that** is possibly being modified by another thread (additions/deletions) then you have a problem.

If all you're ever doing is reading (there's no chance another thread is writing/modifying), then no synchronization is ever needed regardless of the data structure.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the suggestions. It makes a lot sense and clear lot of my doubts as well.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to confirm is. I am using `HashMap` for `tableList` as well. Do I need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` here? Or `HashMap` will do the job for me?

Comment: That's where the last bit comes in. If that `HashMap` could be modified by another thread then yes, you need to either use the `ConcurrentHashMap` or wrap it with `Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));` when you create it. Otherwise you could get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when iterating through the values in your `run()` method.

Comment: Ok. And I am not doing any `tableList.put` operation in my run method. So that means I will be safe here as well to go with `HashMap`. Right?

Comment: As long as there are no other threads that could be doing a `put()` to that `HashMap`, correct. If all you're doing is reading, you don't need sync.

Answer (score 1):

Since tableList won't be modified it is absolutely thread-safe

Answer (score 1):

If you are just calling getters the you should be fine.
But what you are doing is risky and is not a good practice.

If you are worried about "TableConnectionInfo " object being modified then better make it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

To make it safe you need a happens-before relationship between the initialization and each of the getter calls. Anything you do in the main thread before starting a new thread happens-before anything the new thread does, so your code looks safe. See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.5). Specifically, "If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y)." and "A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread."

Answer (score 1):

> In my run method, I am calling get Methods of TableConnectionInfo class so it will be thread safe or not?

Yes, it is thread-safe.

There are two things to consider.

1. There is a "happens before" relationship between the main thread calling `start()` on each thread and the beginning of the threads' `run()` method.  This means that state changes (creation and population of the hash table and its child / content objects) made by the main thread prior to starting the child threads will be visible to the child threads at the point that `run()` starts executing.
2. Assuming that nothing changes the state of those objects after that point, no further synchronization is required.

---

However, you have to perform this analysis on a case-by-case basis.  And it is not sufficient to say that everything is OK because the objects don't change after a certain point.  Indeed, if the `start()` / `run()` happen-before relationship wasn't there, this would NOT be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Makes more sense now. Thanks for making me understand. One more doubt I have is,  I am using `HashMap` for `tableList` here. Do I need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` here? Or `HashMap` will do the job for me?

Comment: For the use-case in your example, `HashMap` is fine.  If you need to be able to update the map, `ConcurrentHashMap` is a good option.